# Is this expression natural in self-introduction?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms

I found this English example conversation in a textbook for Japanese learners of English:

> A: Hi, my name is xxx. What’s yours?

> B: **Mine** is xxx...

I’m okay with “What’s yours?”, but in this situation, the expression “Mine is...” is not familiar to me. Is it often used by English native speakers? I feel it’s better using “My name is...” here.

Comment: You seem happy with the questioner using "_What's yours?_" (instead of "_What's your name?_"), so why shouldn't the responder use "_Mine_" instead of "_My name_"?

Comment: That might be just because I have never heard people say “Mine is ...” to tell their names but “What’s yours”

Comment: In reality people would probably just say "I'm xxx".

Answer (score 1):

Native speakers will often naturally avoid tedious repetition, especially when speaking. We can use a possessive pronoun (mine, his, yours, ours, theirs, or the possessive form of a proper name) to refer to a thing or idea prevously mentioned. Compare:

> My car is red; your car is blue; John's car is green. ('car' appears
> three times)
>
> My car is red; yours is blue; John's is green. ('car' appears once)

Thus in 'A. My name is xxx B. Mine is xxx' repetition of 'name' is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

"Mine is..." is good English.

Self-introduction is often taught on page one of the English book.  But it is actually one of the rarer and more complex interactions.

It is rare to meet new people, and want to tell them your name!  Most people I talk to either know me already, or don't need to know my name.  On the occasions that I am meeting a new person, it is more common to be introduced by someone else.  It is simply not common to go up to someone and say "Hello my name is ...".  And it is just as rare for them to say "Mine is..." or "My name is" in reply.  Think about your life.  How many times did you tell a stranger your name?

The social complexities of meeting a new stranger are great... Is the person a potential friend, lover or rival... Is the person relaxed or formal.  Do they consider themselves to be an equal, superior or inferior (and do I agree, and do they think they know if I agree...)